# xdvipdfmx:fatal: Unable to open "xxx.pdf"

Tags: compiling

I am trying to compile with pdf open in Adobe reader. Anyone knows a workaround other than close the pdf viewer every time?

Comment: Welcome! Is using another view a possibility? On a Mac you could use `preview`, which reloads the file.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am on windows now. (the problem does not occur on Mac)

Comment: @DavidPurton Yes, I think I did duplicate that question.

Comment: Thanks, I will change a pdf viewer then.